# Android accessory mode with multiple peripherals

Tags: android, accessory

Android allows the development of USB accessories using USB Host mode and USB Accessory mode. If I connect a peripheral using accessory mode, would that make the phone unable to connect to other peripherals or to a desktop computer until the aforementioned HW is unplugged?

Usually there is only one USB port on the phone, but please assume the use of a hub.

Comment: were you ever able to talk to simultaneous devices via USB (either host or client mode)? Did you use android acessory?

Comment: @StealthRabbi: No, didn't work.

Comment: May I ask what your alternative solution was? Perhaps you switched to ethernet-based comms?

Comment: @StealthRabbi: I end up using accessory mode with one phone and a single peripheral, and dropped the multi-peripheral idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connecting a peripheral in USB Accessory mode would prevent you from using any other accessory at the same time, and no, a hub will not help.

This is because in Accessory mode, **the peripheral is the USB host** (while the phone is a USB device), and a USB bus can only have one host.  Therefore the Accessory mode restricts you to one accessory at a time.

If instead you used the USB Host APIs to make a (capable) phone the USB host, then there is *some* possibility that you might be able to use multiple USB device peripherals downstream of a hub - at least, the bus topology supports it, though I don't know for an absolute fact that the Android stack will.